# Помогите разобраться с npm как изменить папку глобального пакета

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, manager

Помогите разобраться с npm как изменить папку глобального пакета. изучаю по этой статью но немного не понял здесь. от куда взялся папка bin (если это папка) . и что она вообще из себя представляет ?
Помогите разобраться этим "Как изменить папку глобального пакета в npm правильно?"

http://prgssr.ru/development/vvedenie-v-paketnyj-menedzher-npm-dlya-nachinayushih.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Надо задать префикс для глобальной установки npm:

```
npm config set prefix /var/www/yourfolder --global
```

Comment: /var/www/yourfolder - это адрес к .node_modules_global да ?

Comment: это адрес куда Вам нужно сохранять пакеты глобальные.
после выполнения этой команды,
пакеты глобально должны устанавливаться в prefix + /node_modules
то есть /var/www/yourfolder/node_modules

Comment: они установились но вызов глобальных пакетов не работает

Comment: Установил gulp  

C:\Users\Islombek>npm i gulp -g
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
.......
npm 
C:\Users\Islombek\.node_modules_global\gulp -> C:\Users\Islombek\.node_modules_g
lobal\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
C:\Users\Islombek\.node_modules_global
`-- gulp@3.9.
но после команды "gulp"  пишет что он не является ни внутренней или внешней командой   что делать та (у меня windows os ) ?

Comment: как вообще всё сначала начать, сбросить настройки node (и npm)? я всё удалил все папки связанные с npm  и переустановил node.js  но не помогает помогите пожалуйста

Comment: на винде по другому
надо прописать переменную окружения для пользователя

Comment: C:\Users\Islombek\AppData\Roaming\npm
тут есть 2 файла:  gulp и gulp.cmd    ?